# communication of service with windows application

Tags: .net

I have a windows service running on a machine, On the same machine I have windows application running.
My requirement is:

1. The windows application should send a input to the windows service, based on the  input   given by windows application , windows service would do some calculation and return an input.
2. The input given by windows application to the service would be of "String" type mostly.And the response by windows service to the windows application would be of object type.

Some one suggested Remoting would do my job. Please suggest me with some code(say the method being called by windows application is demo_service(of windows service).

Dot net version:2.0
Studio version:2005

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to communicate with a windows service from an application that interacts with the desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84860/how-to-communicate-with-a-windows-service-from-an-application-that-interacts-wit)