# Listing and terminating processes in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

How can I list and terminate existing processes in .Net application? Target applications are 1) .Net applications, 2) they are instances of the same executable 3) they have unique Ids but I don't know how to get this information from them, 4) they are spawned externally (i.e. I do not have handles to them as I don't create them).

I want to list all processes, get unique ids from them and restart some of them. I assume that all of them are responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/) on interprocess communication, and also [this tutorial](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=101). You can use WCF to query a process, and request a shutdown. Each process will need it's own named pipe. You can generate a unique name at startup, based on the process ID (`Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id`).

All this may be a little heavy weight for some simple communication though. Using the Windows message queue might be an option as well. You can use `process.MainWindowHandle` to get a process' window handle and send custom messages to instances of your application. See [Messages and Message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632590%28VS.85%29.aspx). If you choose to go that way, [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) could be of help.

Comment: My spawned processes already using WCF over named pipes! I just didn't think about naming pipes based on process Ids. Brilliant idea! This is a perfect solution for me. (Messages and pinvoke are not really reliable on >= Vista systems - UAC tends to isolate them unless running as admin).

Answer (score 2):

You can grab a list of running processes with [`Process.GetProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) static method. You can easily query the return value (possibly with LINQ) to get the ones you want.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Process.Kill();
```

Check this out for killing processes:
http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1543.htm

The Process Id is a property of the process. Eg:

```
Process.Id
```

All of the methods available on the process are listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods.aspx

Comment: Thanks Rob, this almost solve my problem. Now I just need some way to get process identity (some basic interprocess communication). Any idea how to do this i.e. how to request a single string from the processes listed by GetProcesses?

Comment: Since some kind of interprocess communication is needed anyway, `Process.Kill()` should be unnecessary. Implement some way for the process to shut down gracefully.