# What to use to make two .net programs transfer information

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I currently have two programs that need to comunicate one with another. It doesn't have to be something complicated, it's just passing data from one to another, all very simple. I was thinking of using .net remoting, but I've heard there's a new thing WCF. Should I go for the .net remoting or try WCF? Or is there something simpler to use?

edit: Both applications are simple, I don't want to have anything to do with IIS, services and such.

Thanks

Comment: Where are the two programs? On the same computer? And how complex is the data? Just messages? or full RPC?

Comment: Both on the same computer, and it's just transferring text and bytes from one side to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic phrase is "inter-process communication".  Then you'll be able to find answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication).

Answer (score 5):

use WCF with named pipes binding, [here](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations) you can find useful examples

Answer (score 2):

WCF has a bit of a learning curve, but it's a very powerful communication framework.  If you have some time to learn it, I'd recommend that over .NET remoting.

If you just need a super-simple mechanism, you could just write data to a file, then read it from the other program (assuming same machine).  If it has to go over the network, using a plain Socket in .NET isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I've used .Net remoting for this in the past, and its worked very well for me.  Its very simple and straightforward for something like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into WCF now, I really don't think you would regret later. WCF is great and useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something really simple, just put the data in a database or a file.