# Active handler in one application from another?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How I can run handler from one application to another, for example:
In application one i have form1 and button.

In application two I have also form1 and button.

Now how I can run handler for button on form1 in first application from applicaton two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need inter process communication (ipc). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication) for more details about ipc in .net.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you're gonna need some form on inter-process communication for these two apps to talk to one another. The simplest option in your case (though by far not the most reliable) is to use System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send().