# What's the best way to IPC between two C# apps (32bit and 64bit)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, ipc

One is 64bit, the other is 32bit. I'm currently doing it while making the 32bit app console, and reading the output. Is there a better way? My data is text.

EDIT: Both executable are on the same machine.

Comment: Can you just compile the 64 bit app as x86 and have a single process?

Comment: In other words the 32/64 part of your question doesn't actually matter. The real issue is that you need to have communication between two distinct processes.

Comment: Well, of course it will be better if I'm somehow able to merge them both into one.

Comment: What is stopping you merging?

Comment: How to merge them if and run the 32bit from 64bit environment?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use 32 bit throughout? If you can then a single process would likely be easier.

Comment: See Related questions list on the right side of this page. There are several topics that are similar to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are constrained to .NET 2.0 then there are a few ways you can do it:

1. if the two apps are on different machines, you can use sockets, or .net Remoting (depending on the complexity of interaction)
2. if the two apps are on the same machine, .net Remoting is an ok choice.

The fact that they are 32 or 64 bit does not influence this in any way.

Comment: @blez: Then I suggest .Net Remoting. It allows you to call methods directly from one program to another.

Comment: Isn't this using sockets? So it can be blocked by firewall or antivirus?

Comment: @blez: On the same machine I think it uses shared memory. You can specify which underlying mechanism you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 2.0 you could [use Remoting](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/a-simple-remoting-example-in-c/).

Comment: This is using Sockets? Can it be blocked by firewall?

Comment: @blez, yes, it can be blocked. You could use a port that is in the exceptions of the firewall.

Comment: So, I better use named pipes or output from the console.

Comment: @blez, yes, named pipes are an alternative.

Comment: @blez, as far as I know, named pipes in .net 2.0 can only be used by calling the native Win32 pipe API. Like I said, remoting can also use shared memory if you're on the same machine.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Out of curiousity: Is the IPCChannel class really using sockets that can be blocked by a firewall?

Comment: @yes4891: It does not use sockets. From MSDN: "Because it does not use network communication, the IPC channel is much faster than the HTTP and TCP channels, but it can only be used for communication between application domains on the same physical computer."

Comment: @Tudor: It looks like it's actually using sockets. Cause one example I tried blocks 8080, which is used by another app.

Answer (score 0):

Doing IPC it doesn't matter whether programs are in 32 bit or 64 bit, so pick the method you want (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/84855/11343)).