# Windows Service (C#) not firing events because no subscription

Tags: service, event-handling

i'm trying to write a windows service firing custom events sending Specific strings. These strings should update a monitoring form (different app). While debugging, i notited that the external app isn't subscribed for receiving those events. I searched the internet but don't know where to start. All articles I found with this kind of problems are looking slightly different.

In Short:

App1 is a windows **service** firing events

App2 is a windows **form** that should receive these events and display received messages.

Where do I start

Comment: How are you trying to subscribe to the events? How does the form "connect" to the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET events are events that fire within a process (app-domain) - you can't subscribe to events in one process from another.

You need to look into some form of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) - [WCF is a good choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication).