# How to send/receive windows messages between VB6 and c#?

Tags: c#, vb6, sendmessage

I am not a good programmer of C#, thus I need a small piece of code to send and receive messages between a C# and VB6 program, I have tried many examples from web but not succeeded due complexity of topic to me, your help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Links to one or more of the examples you have tried would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best choice for .net inter-process communication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was looking for some code sample rather tips or reference as I had mentioned in my question. Anyway, I have managed it by extending following project 
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6945/VB-NET-VB6-and-C-Interprocess-communication-via-Wi)
and now I can pass strings message between both VB6 and C# applications.

Thanks to All for Time and Suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide alot details therefor i could think of quite a few solutions. Probably the  2 best are:

- MSMQ: Read
  http://jwbs-blog.blogspot.de/2009/06/using-msmq-to-communicate-between-net.html
- Named Piped: More Infos http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177696/en-us

Hope this gives you some direction.