# Return string value from one application to other application C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to know how I can send a string value from one application to another application (application2)

Like I received value with Process. StandardOutput. But Doesn't know how to send this type of message!

in Other words application1 capture value come from application2's return.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best choice for .net inter-process communication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication)

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods:

- The most direct form: WCF. One application is the sender, the other the receiver.
- Write your result in a file which is read by another.
- Over the network with Sockets or another type of protocol.
- And much more.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to have one app take a command-line parameter from the other one.

But your question didn't specify if both apps need to be running at the time of the data transfer.

Comment: Yes app1 start app2 when app2 done its work it get exit and return some string. I want that string to catch and add in listbox!