# Using 32 bit C library in published .Net project on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, dll, graphviz, windows-server-2012

I am using graphviz as library in my MVC project. To be more specific I am doing dll import 32 bit C library as gvc.dll and cgraph.dll like [here](http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-graphviz-library-in-net.html).

As I debug my project locally it works fine. However, after web deploying it to my Windows Server 2012 (that is a 64bit OS) it fails to load those dlls. I configured a remote debugger to see that is the case. After if tries to get a Context (gvContext()) it crushed with exeption: *An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)*. My IIS is of 6.2 version.

I need to note that generating images from graphviz using cmd on my windows server works just fine. So I assume that Path variables are correct.

I have found different solutions that I have tried:

- [enable 32bit application](http://pldineshtech.blogspot.com/2012/08/error-attempt-was-made-to-load-program.html)
- doing a web deploy with following configuration: Release for x86
- [running the 64 bit version of IIS Express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EG2c.png)

Nothing worked. I cannot even check if the error has changed as remote debugger doesn't work after I enabled 32bit application.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to find/build x64 version of that native library?

Comment: I couldn't find one. But I am still trying

Comment: In worst case you can create a separate x86 application that will reference native x86 dll and use [interprocess communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication) to offload actual processing out of IIS.